# Looking for formula to search for particular pattern in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013

I am looking for formula to search for "words" with a particular letter pattern, like `INNSA1` or `INMAA4` or `INPTPB`, where the word starts with `IN` and ends with `4`, `1`, `6`, or `B`.  The words are always exactly six characters and the letters can be either upper- or lower-case.

A collection of Excel cells each contain a sentence in which one or more such words will be found (always at least one).  For example:

- My Custom location is INNSA1
- I work at INMAA4
- I want to go to INDEL6
- INNSAB IS BOARDER LOCATION

The word (or words, if more than one), may be in any position in the sentence.  The target words will always be separate words, not part of a larger word.

For each sentence (i.e., cell), I want to search for the presence of any word fitting the described letter pattern, and return this word as a value.

Comment: Heavy vote-down for shouting in all-capitals. Strongly suggest you edit.

Comment: I don't really have a clear picture of your requirement.  Are you looking for the presence (true/false) of a "word" (i.e., character string containing only alphanumerics--letters/numbers but no spaces or other kinds of characters), matching a pattern (starts with `IN`, and ends with `4, 1, 6`, or `b`), which can be located anywhere in a "sentence" but delimited from it by space or punctuation, that is contained in a single cell?  Is it always a separate "word" or can it be a character string embedded in a longer "word"?  (cont'd)

Comment: Is it always exactly 6 characters?  Are the letters always uppercase?  What do the "sentences" look like?  Can the "word" appear more than once, including as part of a larger word?  This would be easier to understand if you include examples of the sentences that represent the range of conditions.

Comment: Also, as Gary's Student interpreted, is the word the only thing in the cell or is it somewhere within other text in a cell (which are very different requirements)?

Comment: I want to search particular pattern in a sentence in a cell. e.g. " My Custom location is INNSA1" OR "I work at INMAA4" or "I want to go to INDEL6"

Comment: In above sentence I want to find/search INNSA1 OR INMAA4 OR INDEL6 and return this word as value

Comment: Almost there.  Questions: 1. Are the words always exactly 6 characters?  2. Are the word's letters always uppercase?  3. Will every sentence always contain a qualifying word?  4. Can a sentence ever contain more than one qualifying word?  5. Is the target word always a separate word, not contained within a larger word?  6. Can a target word appear in any word position in a sentence or will it always be the last word in the sentence?  7. Can a target word appear in more than one sentence or is the target word in each sentence unique?

Comment: 1. Yes it will be always 6 Character and Start with "IN" and end with "1" OR"4" OR "6" OR "B"
2. It may be upper or lower case
3. Yes
4. May be sometimes
5. Yes it is separate word
6. Any where is sentence
7.  Unique

Comment: E.G -My location is INNSA1
My location is INNSA4
My location is INNSA5
My location is INNSA6
My location is INNSA7
My location is INNSA8
INNSAB IS BOARDER LOCATION

Answer (score 1):

This is just an example that you can adapt to your schema.

With data from **A2** to **A26**, in **B2** enter:

```
=IF(AND(LEFT(A2,2)="IN",OR(RIGHT(A2,1)="B",RIGHT(A2,1)="1",RIGHT(A2,1)="4",RIGHT(A2,1)="6")),1+MAX($B$1:B1),"")
```

and copy downward:

[image]

As you see, each item of "good" data is marked with a simple sequential index.

Answer (score 1):

The following will work:

```
=CONCAT(  IF(  ISNUMBER(SEARCH($E$1:$E$4,A1)),  MID(A1,SEARCH($E$1:$E$4,A1),6),  "")  )
```

You build a list of desired search items, in this case in E1:E4, but anywhere, a Named Range, say, or somewhere in physical cells like I used in testing. Incremental improvement of the spreadsheet could include generating the list in the formula itself. Nowadays, using `LET` would allow it to be kept inside the formula, but directly typed. Many ways to do it.

Then use `SEARCH`, which allows the use of wildcards, so a list item like `IN???4` works. If a match exists in the data cell, it will give the starting position of the match. If a match does not exist, it will give an error. `ISNUMBER` tests the results (four in this case, as there are four items being looked for) and is the "test" in the `IF`. For success, it returns the string of the word it matched. For the three failures, the FALSE return is `""`. (Weaknesses:  its result accommodates neither multiple instances of the same word in a single sentence, nor instances of two or more different match words in a single sentence.)

Since the `IF` returns `""` for failures, `CONCAT` isn't really concatenating much. Just the matching word and three nothings, or no word and four nothings. Either way, each sentence is checked and the proper return is made.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do each piece of the problem, but the combination of requirements points to one approach that is simple and straightforward, or a VBA solution.  The non-VBA solution uses helper columns.  The layout of your spreadsheet is unknown, as are other factors, like the number of sentences and the possible number of results, and how you need and want to use the results.  So this answer will be more generic guidance than a specific solution.

Using functions, it will be complicated to search the sentence for potentially more than one target.  A simpler approach is to break the sentence into words and then check the words.  A simple way to parse the sentences is with the built-in Convert Text To Columns wizard.

Assuming the sentences are in column A, leave the next few columns blank for your results.  That way, your results will always be in a known location, visible next to your data.  I'll assume a maximum of two, so columns B and C will contain result values.

Figure the maximum number of words there can be in a sentence, and reserve that many subsequent columns for helper columns.  These will be used to test each word.  Lets say you allow for five words.  Columns D:H will contain formulas pointing to columns I:M, respectively.

Lets say row 2 is your first data row, so the first formula will be in D2, pointing to I2.  The formula will be similar to what Gary's Student suggested:

```
=IF(AND(LEFT(I2,2)="IN",OR(RIGHT(I2,1)="B",RIGHT(I2,1)="1",RIGHT(I2,1)="4",RIGHT(I2,1)="6")),1,0)
```

An alternate formula would be:

```
=IFERROR((LEFT(I2,2)="IN")*(SEARCH(RIGHT(I2,1)," 416b")>1),0)
```

That just gives you a couple of ideas about how to tell whether the target word fits the pattern.  The second formula uses SEARCH (because it isn't case-sensitive), to see if the last character is in your list.  Testing the first two characters for `IN`, and the last character, each result in True or False, which Excel treats as `1` and `0`, respectively.  So if both tests are true the result is `1`, otherwise `0`.

In the SEARCH expression, I started with a blank and test for a result >1.  The reason I did this is because I used MS Office Online to test it, and it thinks the rightmost character of an empty cell is found in position 1 of the test string.

If SEARCH does not find a match, it returns an error, so wrapping the formula in IFERROR ensures that any word not matching results in `0`.

So either formula returns `1` if the word fits your pattern, or `0` if it doesn't (or if its target cell is empty).

Enter either formula in D2, and drag or copy it across to H2, and down to the last row you need.

To fill the target cells, select all the data in column A, and copy and paste it into column I (Text to Columns overwrites the data and starts in the data column).  Select the data in column I.  On the `Data` tab, in the `Data Tools` group, click `Text to Columns`.  You'll get a wizard that is self-explanatory.

Tell it the data is delimited, and select `space` as the delimiter.  It will give you a preview of how it thinks you want it to parse the words.  When you finish the wizard it will put each word in a consecutive cell in the row.

Your formulas in D:H should show at least one `1` in each row.  Those are your words, and their column is in the same relative position as the parsed word.

To get the first word's value in column B, use INDEX and MATCH to find the first `1` in the row in D:H and retrieve the corresponding value from the same row in I:M.  For example, B2 would be:

```
=INDEX(I2:M2,MATCH(1,D2:H2,0))
```

This retrieves the value from the cell in I2:M2 corresponding to where an exact match to `1` was found in D2:H2.

To get the subsequent values for column C (and beyond if there are more than two), there are a number of solutions to find the Nth matching `1`.  Here is [a link](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-nth-match-with-index-match) to one method.